# React Native throws "undefined is not a function" on props.function() call

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have the following `TextInput` component for accepting a username/email from the user. It is nested in a login form component that passes callbacks to its children in order to update its own state.

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      this.updateUser = this.updateUser.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        user: "",
      };
  }

  updateUser(newUser){
      this.setState( oldState =>{
        oldState.user = newUser;
        return oldState;
      });
  }

  <TextInput 
    placeholder="username or email"
    submitHandler={this.updateUser}
    onSubmitEditing={text => this.props.submitHandler(text);}
  />
}
```

But for some reason, submitting the login text throws an exception on the call to `this.props.submitHandler(text)`. This also occurs if I change this line to `this.submitHandler(text)` instead. Is there anything I'm missing here? Does the `TextInput` component not allow me to set new props? Am I using the wrong context for the function call?

Comment: Are you trying to call a function that was passed into the loginForm by its parent? Or are you trying to call updateUser on the login form?

Comment: I want the child TextInput component to update the LoginForm state. So I want the child to call updateUser when someone submits it.

Comment: Then you want `onSubmitEditing={text => this.updateUser(text);}`

Comment: So the context of `this` is the Form itself. Now it makes sense. But I'm still having an issue where the state doesn't properly get modified. If I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.user))` after my call to `this.setState`, it gives an empty string the first time I submit a username and then throws the exception "JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures". Is the parameter to the `onSubmitEditing` callback really the text content of the component?

Comment: `this.setState` isn't synchronous, so a console.log on the next line won't work. If you want to wait for it to complete, you can pass a callback function as the second parameter to setState. As for onSubmitEditing, i looked it up, and you're right: it's not text. That's an event object. You can do `onSubmitEditing={event => this.updateUser(event.nativeEvent.text)}`

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Distilling the previous comments into an answer, onSubmitEditing gives you an event object. (Here is one of the places where a bit more documentation could be added to the React Native project...).

If you do for example `event => console.log(event)` you can see all the properties of the event, among which is nativeEvent, containing the text value you needed (you'll have to refer to event.nativeEvent.text directly to see the value in your debugger though, otherwise it will be null due to the event pooling going on (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling))).

As Nicholas Tower commented, setState() has the option to pass in a function to use when the operation has completed. More details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).